# How to find strong part of each model structure in caffe and combine into new model?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I want to find ineffective design of deep structure model in order to remove its. How to design a deep convolution neural network effectively?

Comment: Selamat pagi.  I don't see how to help you with this question, because you haven't dealt with the issues raised in the question you linked.  I am not clear on when you expect to remove weak parts: during design, implementation, or after running the model.  I know nothing about the data sets, the paradigm of the model, or anything that would keep a worthy answer under 25 pages of text.

Comment: I want any information that can help to design best model to train.